# How to use Websockets with Pyramid and socket.io?

Tags: javascript, python, websocket, socket.io, pyramid

I'm trying to create a simple WebSocket application using Pyramid and socket.io frameworks.
Server-side code:

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from pyramid_socketio.io import SocketIOContext, socketio_manage
import gevent

def includeme(config):
    '''
    This method is called on the application startup.
    '''
    config.add_route('socket.io', 'socket.io/*remaining')

class ConnectIOContext(SocketIOContext):
    # self.io is the Socket.IO socket
    # self.request is the request
    def msg_connect(self, msg):
        print "Connect message received", msg
        self.msg("connected", hello="world")

# Socket.IO implementation
@view_config(route_name="socket.io")
def socketio_service(request):
    print "Socket.IO request running"
    print request
    retval = socketio_manage(ConnectIOContext(request))
    return Response(retval)
```

Client code:

```
<script>
    var socket = null;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        socket = new io.Socket(null, null);
        socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log("Connected");
        socket.send({type: "connect", userid: 123});
    });
    socket.on('message', function(obj) {
        console.log("Message received");
        console.log("Message", JSON.stringify(obj));
        if (obj.type == "some") {
            console.log("do some");
        }
    });
    socket.on('error', function(obj) {
        console.log("Error", JSON.stringify(obj));
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("Disconnected");
    });

    console.log("Connecting...");
    socket.connect();
});
</script>
```

I need this code to use web-sockets for the connection, but it falls back to XHR-polling. 
How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance, Ivan.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to look at the latest release of gevent-socketio, and its documentation at http://gevent-socketio.readthedocs.org/

A major overhaul was done at the PyCon 2012 sprints, by John Anderson, Sébastien Béal and myself.

Comment: To actually answer the question, there should be a {transports: ["websocket"]} object passed in as the second parameter of the io.Socket() call, that is using version 0.6 of the client library.  If you're using the version 0.7+ of the JS lib, it is not set on the server-side.   You must also use a web-sockets enabled web browser (Chrome is one I know that does work).

Comment: gevent-socketio development is pretty dead, don't much rely on it.

Comment: Ravi- Both answers in this tread mention using gevent-socketio, what would you recommend using instead?

Answer (score 2):

You may also have a look at [pyramid_sockjs](https://github.com/fafhrd91/pyramid_sockjs). It integrates well with Pyramid and uses sockjs that fulfills the same role of socket.io and is arguably simpler to understand.

Comment: That has been deprecated in favour of gevent-socketio: https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio/